# Why does python exit on loss of internet

Tags: python

The program I am currently working on pulls information from weather.com every 5 minutes. I am currently having an issue with loss of internet, and if the program tries to check for an update it will exit the program. What is the best method of checking for an error with the internet and having it try again later. This code is a VERY rough mock up right now so sorry about readability.

```
RED_PIN = 17
GREEN_PIN = 22
BLUE_PIN = 24

import pigpio
import time
import pywapi
import string
import math

pi = pigpio.pi()
weather = 'none'
flashelse = 5

while weather != 'Exit':
    print time.ctime()
    #print time.strftime('%l:%M%p %z on %b %d, %Y')
    weather_com_result = pywapi.get_weather_from_weather_com('USTN0268')#USTN0268
    tempc = int(weather_com_result['current_conditions']['temperature'])
    tempf = (tempc*9/5) + 32
    weather = string.lower(weather_com_result['current_conditions']['text'])
    print "Weather.com says: It is " + string.lower(weather_com_result['current_conditions']['text']) + " and", tempf, "F now in Knoxville, TN."

    if weather == 'sunny':
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(RED_PIN, 224) 
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(GREEN_PIN, 255) 
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(BLUE_PIN, 0) 

    elif weather == 'Partly Cloudy':
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(RED_PIN, 0) 
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(GREEN_PIN, 255) 
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(BLUE_PIN, 25) 

    elif weather == 'cloudy':
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(RED_PIN, 82) 
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(GREEN_PIN, 0) 
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(BLUE_PIN, 255) 

    elif weather == 'rain shower':
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(RED_PIN, 0) 
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(GREEN_PIN, 0) 
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(BLUE_PIN, 255) 

    elif weather == 'Thunderstorm':
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(RED_PIN, 255) 
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(GREEN_PIN, 0) 
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(BLUE_PIN, 0) 

    elif weather == 'Snow':
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(RED_PIN, 0) 
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(GREEN_PIN, 174) 
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(BLUE_PIN, 255) 

    elif weather == 'Exit':
        break

    else:
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(RED_PIN, 50) 
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(GREEN_PIN, 0) 
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(BLUE_PIN, 0) 
        time.sleep(2)
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(RED_PIN, 0) 
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(GREEN_PIN, 0) 
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(BLUE_PIN, 0) 
    #text_file.close()
    time.sleep(300)

print("Exiting...")

time.sleep(.1)
pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(RED_PIN, 50) 
pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(GREEN_PIN, 0) 
pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(BLUE_PIN, 0) 

time.sleep(1)
pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(RED_PIN, 0)
pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(GREEN_PIN, 0)
pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(BLUE_PIN, 0)

pi.stop()
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to stackoverflow. To attract better answers, you should trim down your sample program until you get a minimal sample that shows the problem. Checkout this page on [how to create a good code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `pywapi` but I'm guessing that `pywapi.get_weather_from_weather_com()` will raise some sort of `SocketException` if there's no connection so you should wrap it with `try/except`.

```
try:
    weather_com_result = pywapi.get_weather_from_weather_com('USTN0268')
except SocketException: # or what ever exception type ptwapi raises
    # probably log the exception for later review
    continue
```

Comment: Blank except is a bad idea, if you expect a socket error you should catch one

Comment: Next to the 'catch all'  anti-pattern, you will probably want an error message printed somewhere.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Agreed, but since I'm not familiar with `pywapi` I didn't want OP to use that, I will edit my answer.

Comment: …and if you really want to continue whatever happens (understandable for services), the very minimum is to log the exceptions you don't expect somewhere where you can review them should the program fail.

Comment: @spectras Totally acceptable, but I'm not here to write the whole logic for the OPs program :)

Comment: My comment just lagged behing, had only seen the first one. Anyway, this should be enough for the op to fix his issue, so +1.

Comment: Thanks you all for the help!